# how to create an object with a user attached in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a product that the current authenticated user created.

The user has a relationship with the product entity, i need to make a way for a user to create product with the user associated with it.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database), but it doesn't cover how to store a product with a current user

This is what i have so far

**ProductController.php**

```
  public function create(Request $request)
    {

      $category = new Category();
      $category->setName($request->get('category'));

      $user = new User();
      // how would i get the current user and set it to a product.
      $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $product = new Product();
      $product->setName($request->get('title'));
      $product->setPrice($request->get('price'));
      $product->setDescription($request->get('description'));

      $product->setCategory($category);

      $entityManager->persist($category);
      $entityManager->persist($product);
      $entityManager->flush();


      return $this->redirectToRoute('products');

    }
```

Should i use this method or try something else ?

**Entity\User.php**

```
public function addProduct(Product $product): self
{
    if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
        $this->products[] = $product;
        $product->setUser($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Entity\Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(int $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see, your relation works through `addProduct()` method, but in your controller, you don't call `addProduct()` anywhere.

try following...

```
$entityManager->persist($user) // you forgot to persist a new User
$entityManager->persist($category);
$entityManager->persist($product);
$user->addProduct(product)
$entityManager->flush(); // now try to flush...
```

**Offtopic and a bit 
constructive criticism**

Just by looking at your controller I assume you playing around with Symfony and in particular with doctrine. If it is so, consider following. If not then just ignore it ;)

- rename `Product->user` to `Product->createdBy` This naming convention makes it more obvious.
- For that case it's better to switch from a bidirectional relation (your current state) to a unidirectional (google for it, but in short -> just throw away `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` part in you Product <-> User relation )

Comment: let me give this a go.

Comment: im getting `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null`

Comment: maybe because you set `nullable=false` in your User Class and in your controller you create a "blank" User without setting any value. So you could either remove all `nullable=false` notaions *OR* you call setters on you User Class with data. 
P.S. Since you didn't posted you User class - I can only guess

Comment: i fixed it by `$user = $this->getUser()` thanks for your help v :)